# Is it possible to know if a serialVersionUID was automatically generated or not?

Tags: java, serialization

I'm wondering whether it's possible to figure out if some serialVersionUID has been automatically generated (by the JVM) or whether a static one is explictly defined in the class.

Any clue if it's possible to do, and if so how?

Comment: As the theoretically correct answer is 'no', you might want to specify why exactly you need the distinction. In some cases, there might be heuristics which are good enough.

Comment: are you talking about examining the byte stream?

Comment: Why the heck is this important? In which case does the JVM generate `serialVersionUID`s?

Comment: The reason is that we would like to force the coder to put his own serialVersionUID and NOT to rely on the JVM to do it (since this one isn't constant over time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reflection.Here's an example (I haven't checked the exact contract for the serialVersionUID field, though):

```
public class SerialTest {
    private static class A implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    }

    private static class B implements Serializable {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("A : " + containSerialVersionUID(A.class));
        System.out.println("B : " + containSerialVersionUID(B.class));
    }

    private static boolean containSerialVersionUID(Class<?> clazz) {
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.getName().equals("serialVersionUID")
                && field.getType() == Long.TYPE
                && Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())
                && Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())
                && Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: stupid me, assuming reflection couldn't give away static fields... Thanks!

Comment: extra note: checking for private isn't required (while it's still good practice to make its own serialVersionUID private)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try through introspection to check for the field serialUID ?
I don't know if the JVM will assign it this way or just store it in a different manner when generating it.

Regards,
 Stéphane